# Basic power calculation for clinical trial enrollment

Tags: statistical-power

If I know that a disease has a 50% prevalence in a population, how many individuals do I need to screen for enrolment in order to get six individuals who are positive for this disease with 80%, 90% and 95% power?

Answer (score 1):

"Power" is a property of a hypothesis test, so I'm not sure that really applies here. Perhaps you could expand on what you're looking for?  In the absence of such an explanation, I'll just answer the question as posed.

Let's let the prevalence of the disease be $p = 0.5$.  The question boils down to the number of trials necessary in order to see 6 successes. This can be computed using the negative binomial.

The negative binomial distribution will allow us to determine the probability it will take $n$ draws from the population (i.e. enrolments) in order to get $r$ successes (i.e. disease positive people).

Evaluating the density using the criteria provided, we find:

- There is at least a 80% probability you will find 6 positive patients when you enroll 15 patients (real probability is 85%, but fewer enrolled patients will result in a probability less than 80%)
- There is at least a 90% probability you will find 6 positive patients when you enroll 17 patients
- There is at least a 95% probability when you enroll 18 patients.

You can verify this using R

````r
p <- 0.5
r <- 6
enrollments <- 6:20

# qbinom returns number of failures, so add number of
# successes for total number of trials
qnbinom(c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95), size=r, prob=p) + r
[1] 15 17 18
```
````